# How can I make UIControl appear as a button in XCUITest?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have created a subclass of UIControl that should behave similarly to a UIButton.

When I run my UI tests using XCUITest the button is appearing in `XCUIApplication().staticTexts` rather than the expected `XCUIApplication().buttons`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hunting around I found that this is down to the accessibility trait not being set. For example if I have the following class;

```
class ActivityButton: UIControl {

    private let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return activityIndicator
    }()

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return titleLabel
    }()

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // This is the required call to make the control appear 
        // as a button in ui tests
        accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton
        addSubview(activityIndicator)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        createConstraints()
    }    

}
```